# using BING maps on iPhone / iPad sdk

Tags: iphone, ios4, bing-maps, bing

has anyone had any experience using BING maps on the iphone/ipad? We have an application which uses the googlemaps default map in the SDK, but we now have a requirement to use BING maps instead.

I am thinking we'd use the BING API via a UIWebView? 
Has anyone else tried this? Thanks for any information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a bing API n a UIWebView, however the JS is rather costly, yet until I find and discover a BING SDK for the iPhone/iPad will probably have ot resort to that.

One other thing you can try (which I've just started down the path of), is trying to use HTML5 to cache a bunch of the is parts to it and see if that might speed the implementation up.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Will look in to the HTML5 option, but for now the UIWebView will have to do (hurried fix needed!) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the http://ibing.codeplex.com/ project on Codeplex was created with the intent of adding Bing Maps support for iOS and MacOS developers. It doesn't look to have been updated in over a year, and I don't know if it even works. Just thought I'd post it for anyone interested in checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

this maybe another approach worth looking into

https://github.com/mtigas/iOS-MapLayerDemo

Answer (score 0):

Recently announced and [posted on the Bing Maps Blog](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2011/05/05/new-bing-maps-ios-sdk.aspx) on 5 May 2011, a new Bing Maps control/SDK is now available for iOS.

> The Bing Maps iOS Control is an Objective-C control for embedding maps directly into native iOS apps. With a rich, gesture-based UI provided by Seadragon, the Bing Maps iOS Control provides support for adding pushpins and other overlays to the map, allows your device location to be displayed, and provides the ability to retrieve contextual information for a given map location.

Link to download the SDK:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6e01a102-49ed-409e-b384-0b67521fb612